# how to access lazy loaded service methods from caller method?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, lazy-loading

In my module I am lazy loading(`lazy.module.ts`) a module from `app.component.ts` by using a testService. After successfully loaded the function I need to access a function from where I loaded the module. How can I achieve?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _testService: TestService) {}

  //lazy start
  public loadme = function(){

    console.log('begin load')
    this._testService.load();    
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="loadme()">Load me</button>
```

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NgModuleFactoryLoader, Injector, NgModuleRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root', })
export class TestService {

  constructor(
    private loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  private moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any>;

  load(): void {

        const path = 'src/app/lazy.module#LazyModule'
        this
            .loader
            .load(path)
            .then(moduleFactory => {
                this.moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector).instance;                
               console.log('loaded');  

               //I NEED TO ACCESS THE 
               //lazyService.hello()   function here
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('error loading module', err); 
            });

  }
}
```

**lazy.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LazyService } from './lazy.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  providers:[ LazyService ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

**lazy.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LazyService {

  constructor() {    
    console.log('lazy service constructed');    
  }

  //I NEED TO ACCESS THIS FUNCTION RIGHT AFTER LAZY LOADS
  public hello = function():void{

    console.log('Hello from lazy service');
  }
}
```

Comment: If you inject a dependency, it gets loaded in the module it is injected (in your case, app component). Also, `{ providedIn: 'root' }` forces the module to be imported in the root module, a.k.a AppModule. finally, if you have to use a method from a service in your root module, I don't see the point of lazy loading this method since you will always use it at application startup. Don't ask how you can achieve a bad design, but rather how to impove this bad design !

Comment: @trichetriche I am new to Angular and its my mistake I removed `{ providedIn: 'root' }`. I need to lazy loads services and access their methods from other modules or service is that posible?

Comment: what is the error now .?

Comment: @FranklinPious there is no error I need to improve my design too access lazyloaded service methods from root

Comment: No it's not possible. If you need to access a method from a service, you need to load that service. If you access it from your root module, then it's loaded at startup, so it's not lazy loaded ... Seems pretty clear ! As I said, consider creating an eagerly loaded service with the methods you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide service tokens in `lazy.module.ts`

```
  ,
  providers:[
    {provide: 'LazyService', useClass: LazyService}
  ]
```

`test.service.ts`

Since you have module reference, you can use its injector to create required service

```
.then(moduleFactory => {
   this.lazyModule = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);

    var lazyService = this.lazyModule.injector.get('LazyService');
    lazyService.hello()

})
```

Comment: I am getting an error `error loading module TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Its self explainatory, injector is undefined. You probably don't want `.instance` as it is module not moduleRef. Snippet updated.

Comment: `const yourService=moduleInjector.get('LazyService');` getting another error `error loading module Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LazyService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LazyService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for LazyService!`

Comment: what should I pass as `YourServiceToken` in your code snippet

Comment: The same thing that you would declare in constructor where you would like to get injected dependencies. Most commonly it is a class name (the same thing used to delcare provider).

Comment: I cannot get `lazyService` to a variable its give the above error

Comment: Use common string as injection token then since you cannot use type token as you cannot import it from lazy module. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/dependency-injection-and-providers/tokens/#_string_tokens

Comment: can you please update the code snippet I am new to Angular

Comment: Im glad you sorted that out :)